# doccano server Files cannot be import to database

Tags: postgresql, doccano

I install doccano using pip installation method using postgresql as DB
i tried to upload dataset into the docanno for tagging
The .jsonl file is uploaded successfully, but cannot be imported into the database
want to look for doccano logs to debug but can't find it.
in which location can i find the doccano logs

my environment
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Python Version Used: Python 3.10.6
Doccano installation method: pip installation method using DB postgresql